# Laravel Dusk Tests & Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: curl, bitbucket-pipelines, laravel-dusk

I am trying to run some laravel dusk tests while as part of my bitbucket pipeline. I am getting the below error:

```
E                            38 / 38 (100%)Invitation Code is: FktOXSfApm4J0glD28znPtUYK
Time: 1.45 minutes, Memory: 24.00MB
There were 38 errors:
1) Tests\Browser\NewUserRegisterTest::testInvitationIsRequired
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless"]}}}
Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:292
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:126
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/DuskTestCase.php:45
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/DuskTestCase.php:32
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:189
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:768
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:190
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:92
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:64
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/Browser/NewUserRegisterTest.php:40
```

All tests failed with the same error. I am stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Did you get that fixed?

Comment: Nope. I didn't pursue it after some time. I hurt ran the testa on my Dev box.

Comment: Okay no worries, I got it finally working today :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the Laravel Dusk Test Case file, the tests will be run at ip 9515. But since pipeline runs on its own local area, it doesn't use 9515. That's why you get an error. I recommend that you run Laravel Dusk tests in your local area. The pipeline is not working properly because you are constantly receiving errors.